# Custom nameservers on Google Cloud VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, nameservers

Is it possible to enter custom Nameservers (NS1.XXX.YYY and NS2.XXX.YYY) with Host Name (NS1 with IP: 111.222.333.444 and NS2 with IP: 111.222.333.444) registered with Godaddy when creating a Google Cloud DNS zone?

IP address (111.222.333.444) that I use when registering a hostname at Godaddy is the one that I get when creating the VM instance.

I want to create custom Host Names and that Host Names use as Nameservers (NS1.XXX.YYY and NS2.XXX.YYY) at Godaddy and use it with Google Cloud VM instead of predefined nameservers provided by Google cloud (ns-cloud-c1.googledomains.com.; ns-cloud-c2.googledomains.com.;...)

Can I do that or I have to use the NS parameters provided by Google Cloud predefined in the Cloud DNS setting?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, for public zones you can use custom name servers.

See how to here: https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/update-name-servers